# Overlay an element without replacing it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Say I have something like this:

```
<a href="/ad.php?go=123">
    <div class="ad"></div>
</a>
```

Lets say the `<div>` has height of 50, width of 250, and a background of some generic banner.

What I want to do is not to replace it (which implies erasing the original) but rather create an (what I envision to be) absolutely positioned copy except with a background of white and a higher `z-index`, rendering the ad invisible.

Think of this as something adblock does, except without toggling off the actual ad, but rather overlaying it with white.

What's the best way to go about something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: "absolutely positioned copy except with a background of white and a higher z-index" Ok, so whats the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select the anchor and set `visibility:hidden`. The element will remain, the layout will stay the same, but the ad won't be visible.

```
$('a').css('visibility', 'hidden'); // replace 'a' with the appropriate selector for your ads, of course
```

**Doing it the hard way**

Get the dimensions of the selected element using `.width()` and `.height()`. Create a new element and set the height, width, and zindex using `.css()`. The part that sucks is positioning it. Usually, you can get away with just using `.offset()` to get the top and left. Sometimes it's trickier. I'd recommend the [jQuery UI positioning plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/). Furthermore, the positioning will be off when the browser window is resized. You'll need to handle `$(window).resize()` and reposition all your overlays. It'll flicker, it'll look like crap... which is why you should just use `visibility:hidden`. But, suit yourself.

But at a minimum:

```
var $a = $('.ad');


$a.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.before($('<div></div>')
         .addClass('ad-overlay')
         .css({
            height: $this.height(),
            width: $this.width(),
            'z-index': 1000,
            'background-color': 'white',
            position: 'absolute',
            top: $this.offset().top,
            left: $this.offset().left
        }));
});
```

Here's a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/HackedByChinese/SF4tw/4/

Comment: Not an option. For the purposes of this exercise, the element has to be visible, just overlayed.

Comment: My question is - how to design a superpositioned element and place it exactly over the original element in question.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like something I could use.

Comment: Ah, what the hell. Added the repositioning on window resize to the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do that too : )

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need a div at the bottom of your site to enlarge and place over the top.

Then enlarge it and position it over the top.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML += "<div id=\"adblocker\" style=\"background-color:#FFF; position:absolute; z-index:999; display:block;\"></div>"
var blocker = document.getElementById('adblocker');
var ad = document.getElementById('ad');
blocker.style.top = ad.offsetTop+"px";
blocker.style.left = ad.offsetLeft+"px";
blocker.style.width = ad.offsetWidth+"px";
blocker.style.height = ad.offsetHeight+"px";
</script>
```

I have tested this in Firefox & Chrome, please tell me if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a more generic option, inserting the overlay into the element you want to hide

```
var overlayElement = function (element) {
    var originalDiv = element,
        overlayDiv = document.createElement('div'),
        overlayStyle = overlayDiv.style;
    originalDiv.style.position = 'relative';
    // either:
    overlayStyle.position = 'absoluete';
    overlayStyle.top = 0;
    overlayStyle.left = 0;
    overlayStyle.width = '100%';
    overlayStyle.height = '100%';
    overlayStyle.background = 'white';
    // or pre set it with a css class and:
    overlayDiv.className = 'overlay-div';
    // finally:
    originalDiv.appendChild(overlayDiv);
    return overlayDiv; // just so you can go on working with it
}
var myOverlayElement = overlayElement(document.getElementById('divId'));
```